# How do I know how many children elements are above me

Tags: jquery

**MY HTML**

```
<ul style="height: 792px;" id="scroller1" data="business_ids" class="business_types simply-scroll-list">
         <li style="color:#c3c3c3;">Select Business Type</li>
         <li><a class='types' href="#" data="59" class="selected">Table Service</a></li>
     <li><a class='types' href="#" data="60">Quick Service</a></li>
     <li><a class='types' href="#" data="75">Bar Nightclub</a></li>
     <li><a class='types' href="#" data="61">Take-Out &amp; Delivery</a></li>
     <li><a class='types' href="#" data="67">Drive-Thru</a></li>
     <li><a class='types' href="#" data="68">Yogurt &amp; Ice Cream</a></li>
     <li><a class='types' href="#" data="69">Catering</a></li>
     <li><a class='types' href="#" data="70">Coffee</a></li>
     <li><a class='types' href="#" data="58">General Retail</a></li>
     <li><a class='types' href="#" data="55">Tobacco Store</a></li>
     <li><a class='types' href="#" data="63">Liquor Store</a></li>
     <li><a class='types' href="#" data="62">Grocery Store</a></li>
     <li><a class='types' href="#" data="73">Convenience Store</a></li>
     <li><a class='types' href="#" data="66">Video Rentals</a></li>
     <li><a class='types' href="#" data="71">Fabric</a></li>
     <li><a class='types' href="#" data="72">Jewelry</a></li>
     <li><a class='types' href="#" data="54">Bakery</a></li>
     <li><a class='types' href="#" data="64">Hair Salon</a></li>
     <li><a class='types' href="#" data="74">Medical &amp; Health Spa</a></li>
     <li><a class='types' href="#" data="65">Automotive</a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>

</ul>
```

**MY jQuery**

```
var element = $("#scroller1").find('a[data=72]');
```

this will select this element

```
     <li><a class='types' href="#" data="72">Jewelry</a></li>
```

but how do i count how many a tags with the `class='types'` above me ...so in this case 14 a tags above ...any ideas

Comment: Trying to do something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/ryyuX/)? (I just bold the previous elements, but you can easily count them).

Comment: How are you bringing this data, if that is hard-coded, then best from jquery, if it is through array or dynamic it will be very fast and easy to get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the jquery index method: http://api.jquery.com/index/

So you would say:

```
var element = $("#scroller1").find('a[data=72]');
var itemsAboveCount = $('.types').index(element) - 1;
```

**COMPLETE EXAMPLE WITH CODE**

```
<html>
<head>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


    function test()
    {
        var element = $("#scroller1").find('a[data=72]');
        alert($('.types').index(element));
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="test();">
<ul style="height: 792px;" id="scroller1" data="business_ids" class="business_types simply-scroll-list">
         <li style="color:#c3c3c3;">Select Business Type</li>
         <li><a class='types' href="#" data="59" class="selected">Table Service</a</li>
         <li><a class='types' href="#" data="60">Quick Service</a></li>
         <li><a class='types' href="#" data="75">Bar Nightclub</a></li>
         <li><a class='types' href="#" data="61">Take-Out &amp; Delivery</a></li>
         <li><a class='types' href="#" data="67">Drive-Thru</a></li>
         <li><a class='types' href="#" data="68">Yogurt &amp; Ice Cream</a></li>
         <li><a class='types' href="#" data="69">Catering</a></li>
         <li><a class='types' href="#" data="70">Coffee</a></li>
         <li><a class='types' href="#" data="58">General Retail</a></li>
         <li><a class='types' href="#" data="55">Tobacco Store</a></li>
         <li><a class='types' href="#" data="63">Liquor Store</a></li>
         <li><a class='types' href="#" data="62">Grocery Store</a></li>
         <li><a class='types' href="#" data="73">Convenience Store</a></li>
         <li><a class='types' href="#" data="66">Video Rentals</a></li>
         <li><a class='types' href="#" data="71">Fabric</a></li>
         <li><a class='types' href="#" data="72">Jewelry</a></li>
         <li><a class='types' href="#" data="54">Bakery</a></li>
         <li><a class='types' href="#" data="64">Hair Salon</a></li>
         <li><a class='types' href="#" data="74">Medical &amp; Health Spa</a></li>
         <li><a class='types' href="#" data="65">Automotive</a></li>
<li><a href="#"></a></li>

</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: `element` is the only child of a `<li>` , the index is not what you are looking for

Comment: Not quite sure I am following you, the jquery index method searches for an element (my example named element) in a jquery selector and brings back the index of that element?

Answer (score 1):

Above you in termo of the DOM you have 0  `<a>` tags with  `class='types'` because each `a` tag is the only child of a `li` and so if you go up the DOM tree you have only a `<li>` and then an `<ul>`

In any case you could do:

```
var element = $("#scroller1").find('a[data=72]');
//Count the number of <li> element which has a direct child which is an <a> witch class types
var howmany = element.parent().prevAll('li:has(a.types)').length;
alert(howmany);
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/GZXpY/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var $refElem = $("#scroller1").find('a[data=72]');
var noOfElemBeforeRefElem = $refElem.parent().prevAll().filter(function(){
   return ($(this).has('a.types').length > 0);  
}).length;
//This will give the number of elements above the reference element.
alert(noOfElemBeforeRefElem);
```